# Use SPServices to Grab Recently Modified DOcuments

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, spservices

I'm looking to build a list of files that have recently been modified in my SharePoint Online library.  I am using SPServices to query my SharePoint Library.

Here is my code:

```
var fieldsToRead ="<ViewFields></ViewFields>";
var query = "<Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value Type=\"Date\">"+ $('#in_FromDate').val() +"</Value></Geq></Where></Query>";

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    webURL: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite(),
    listName: "Documents",
    CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
    CAMLQuery: query,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
            var dtModified = $(this).attr("ows_Modified").split(";#")[1]; 
            var LinkToDoc = $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split(";#")[1];
            var Type = $(this).attr("ows_FSObjType").split(";#")[1];    //  0 = File | 1 = Folder

            //Process Result
        });
    }
});
```

This works, but only for the Root of my Document Library.

Can I adjust my query or code to show all documents/folders that have been modified since the supplied date? (in_FromDate in the example above.)

Comment: You may have to add scope as RecursiveAll to your view attirbutes. Take a look - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/33239/407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'  /></QueryOptions>",
```

to your SPServices code.